# substrings with sum equals to a number without import

Tags: python, string, substring

I have a string S='n1,n2,n3.......nk' (ex'3,0,4,0,3,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,5,0,4,2') and a number m= S (es 9). I want to know how many substrings with sum equals m there are.

I used this code which seems to work. I have a 1 second timeout and this code fails a few milliseconds test with very long strings of numbers ( like 10000 times 1). How could I optimize it? (no import !!)

```
def ex1(int_seq, subtotal):
    list_numbers = list(map(int,int_seq.split(",")))
    c = 0
    count_number = list_numbers
    for i in range(len(list_numbers)):
        c += count_number.count(subtotal)
        count_number= [a+b for a,b in zip(count_number,list_numbers[i+1:]) ]
    return c
```

with int_seq='3,0,4,0,3,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,5,0,4,2' and subtotal = 9

output = 7

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you saying that your code must complete within a certain amount of time but that for some input (what input?) it exceeds that time (by how much?)

Comment: Check out: [Number of subarrays having sum exactly equal to k](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-subarrays-sum-exactly-equal-k/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a quadratic solution.  It sounds like you need a solution that is linear.  Here's a brief hint, because you really should solve this yourself.

Try creating a cumulative sum `accumulate` such that `accumulate[i]` is the sum of all the elements up to and including `i`.  Now for each index `i` and element `accumulate[i]`, you need to find how many indexes `j > i` are there such that `accumulate[j] == accumulate[i] + subtotal`.  (Hint, you'll need do keep a dictionary mapping values in accumulate to their index).

There may be better solutions, but that's the first that comes to mind.